# how to group by, JOIN and perform aggregation correctly with an existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table "t1":

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+---------------------+
| id | name    | country | isreg | time                |
+----+---------+---------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | felix   | isr     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  2 | alex    | rus     |     0 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  3 | avi     | isr     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  4 | dima    | rus     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  5 | nadav   | isr     |     0 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  6 | vitaly  | rus     |     0 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  7 | miko    | ita     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  8 | jiji    | ita     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
|  9 | vieri   | ita     |     0 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
| 10 | maldini | ita     |     1 | 2016-10-02 15:23:32 |
+----+---------+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

and what I want to achieve is this: (based on the isreg column)

```
+---------+------------+----------------+
| country | registered | notregistered  |
+---------+------------+----------------+
| isr     |     2      |              2 |
| rus     |     1      |              2 |
| ita     |     3      |              1 |
+---------+------------+----------------+
```

but I am having trouble as to how to construct this query, I want an explanation(PLEASE) in to how this can be done and what is the logic that I should follow when performing similar operations?

EDIT: I just need to count how many registraited from each country and how many are not

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use case expressions to do conditional counting.

Comment: I don't need them I just need to count how many registraited from each country and how many are not

Comment: Have you tried using sub queries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to just want an aggregation:

```
select country, sum(isreg) as registered, sum(1 - isreg) as notregistered
from t1
group by country;
```

I'm not sure what explanation is needed.  The logic seems pretty clear, and a `join` is not necessary.

Comment: Will OP's teacher accept that explanation "The logic seems pretty clear"?

Comment: wow, I did not think it's that simple... thank you very much :)

Comment: What I can say about `sum(1 - isreg)` this is just awesome +1

Answer (score 2):

You may use this script as well

```
SELECT country, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN isreg=1 THEN 1 END) AS Registered,
       SUM(CASE WHEN isreg=0 THEN 1 END) AS NotRegistered
From Table
GROUP BY country
```